# Caution Statement in LaTex?

Tags: latex

Question:

I use caution statements in my LaTex documents using the code below which works, but I need the caution symbol to be centre aligned against the text like below image that shows current and expected. How?

```
\newlist{Caution}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Caution]{label=\scshape{\color{black}\colorbox{yellow}{{\textbf{{\faWarning} caution}}}},leftmargin=*}

\begin{Caution}
\item {A hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result in minor or moderate njury.} 
\end{Caution}
```

[image]

Edit 1: Minimum Reproducible Example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,%
top=30mm,bottom=20mm,footskip=10mm,headsep=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor, fontawesome}
\usepackage{multicol}
\twocolumn
\newlist{Caution}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Caution]{label=\scshape{\color{black}\colorbox{yellow}{{\textbf{{\faWarning} caution}}}},leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
\begin{Caution}
        \item {A hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result in minor or moderate injury.} 
\end{Caution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try a `\raisebox` But without a [mcve], it is difficult to be more helpful.

Comment: I added a MRE, Please help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the vertical position of any box with the command `\raisebox` and this can be used to raise or lower the label. But it is not a very good idea for your problem as the amount that the label must be lowered depends on the number of lines in the item text. More, it is not very easy to pass optional positioning parameters to a label, and this solution really lacks flexibility, but I included it for comparisons and completeness.

I propose another solution with `minipage`s. It is sufficient to put the caution label and the text in minipages and to specify a center (`[c]`) vertical alignment.
The width of either parts are computed with the `calc` package and it adapts to font size modifications. There is an optional argument that allows to control the spacing between the label and the text. Default value of this parameter mimics the spacing in a list, but it can be adjusted if required.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,%
top=30mm,bottom=20mm,footskip=10mm,headsep=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor, fontawesome}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\twocolumn

\newcommand{\cautionmark}{\scshape{\color{black}\colorbox{yellow}{\faWarning caution}}}
\newlist{Caution}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Caution]{label=\raisebox{-0.5cm}[0pt][0pt]{\cautionmark},leftmargin=*}

\newcommand{\newcaution}[2][0.7em]{
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\widthof{\cautionmark}}
    \cautionmark
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth-\widthof{\cautionmark}-#1}
    #2
  \end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{Caution}
  \item A hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result in
        minor or moderate injury.
\end{Caution}

\newcaution{A hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result 
in minor or moderate injury.}

\newcaution[1cm]{A hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result 
in minor or moderate injury.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Much appreciated.